# progress dialog doesnt work with custom list adapter

Tags: android, eclipse, progressdialog

progress dialog doesnt work while listing data with listAdapter

i think its all about sending activity to myAdapter

```
final myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(rss_list_activity.this, liste);


    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Title", 
            "Message", true);
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              dialog.dismiss();
              }
           };
        Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {  
           public void run() {
        getListFromXml();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
              handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
              }
           };
        checkUpdate.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's some information on threading, i would use an AsyncTask if I were you:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Something similar to this should work:

```
LoadListTask tsk = new LoadListTask();
tsk.execute((Void) null);
```

with this somewhere

```
private class LoadListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<theType>>
{
    final ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainClass.this, "Title", "Message", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<theType> result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        final myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(rss_list_activity.this, result);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<theType> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        return getListFromXml();
    }
}
```

Comment: dialog = ProgressDialog.show(main.this, "Title", "Message", true); has error i cant write "main.this"

Comment: eror is "No enclosing instance of the type main is accessible in scope"

Answer (score 0):

use `dialog.show();` to show dialog. you are directly dismissing the dialog using `dialog.dismiss();`